# Prove existence of disjoint open sets containing disjoint closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be disjoint
closed subsets of X. Prove that there exist open subsets $U_1, U_2 ⊂ X$ so that
$F1 ⊂ U1, F2 ⊂ U2$ and $U1 ∩ U2 = ∅$.

[Prove existence of disjoint open sets containing disjoint closed sets in a topology induced by a metric.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133049/prove-existence-of-disjoint-open-sets-containing-disjoint-closed-sets-in-a-topol)

I read this similar question , can't get why U and V are disjoint sets, isn't it possible that $\exists x \not\in A,B$ and $d(x,A)=d(X,B)$ ?

Appreciate any help.

Comment: $U$ and $V$ are defined with $<$ and $>$, so such an $x$ would be in neither set—it doesn't violate disjointness.

Comment: Did you mistake "$<$" and "$>$" for "$\le$" and "$\ge$" respectively?

Comment: @GregMartin @ Apass.Jack got where i was wrong . thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Suppose $\exists x \not\in A,B$ and $d(x,A)=d(X,B)$. Since it is not true that $d(x,A)\lt d(x,B)$, by the definition of $U$, we know $x\notin U$. That means $x$ is not a common element of $U$ and $V$. Well, that goes along with the conclusion that $U$ and $V$ are disjoint.

---

Let us prove $U$ and $V$ are disjoint in detail.

Towards a contradiction, suppose $U$ and $V$ are not disjoint. That means $\exists y\in X$ such that $y\in U$ and $y\in V$. $\ y\in U$ implies $d(y,A)\lt d(y,B)$. $\ y\in V$ implies $d(y,A)\gt d(y,B)$. Hence $d(y,A)$ and $d(y,B)$ are two real numbers that are smaller to each other, which is a contradiction.

Hence, $U$ and $V$ are disjoint.